# Default values for arguments when argument is null?

Tags: dart

Is there any way to get this to return "default" without writing out special functions to check the argument and set it?

```
void main() {
    Thing stuff = Thing(text: null);
  print(stuff.text);
}


class Thing{
  String text;

  Thing({this.text: "default"});
}
```

I have a map coming in from Firebase and sometimes values will be null and I'd like my class to use its default values when it is provided null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Thing({text}) : this.text = text ?? 'default';
```

You will need to add this small snippet because default values in constructors only work  if there is ***no*** value specified.
The `??` *null-aware* operator will only use the `'default'` value if the value that is being passed is actually `null` (which will also be the case if no value is specified).

Comment: I get an error `Fields cannot be initialized in both the parameter list and the initializers.`

Comment: Nevermind, if I follow your example exactly it works.